# Error running an application

Tags: vb.net, exe

Sorry if this is not suitable place to post it.

I have completed my program and already build it. it has no problem running on my laptop but when i run on other laptop, there is an error appear

```
To run this application you must first install one of the following version of
.NET framework: v4.0.xxxxx
Contact your application publisher about obtaining the appropriate version of .Net framework
```

How do i check my program using which kind of .Net framework for running the program? can i just disable it?

Comment: No, if you create an app using VB.NET you are using the NET Framework and you cannot disable it. You need to install it on the target machine if it is not installed. And to discover the version used you need to look at your Visual Studio Project, right clicking your project, select properties and look in the Application Tab at the Target Framework combo

Comment: Could an error message be _any_ clearer?

Comment: What os are your laptops using?

Comment: my laptop running on Windows 7. i test on Windows XP. The error is like above

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install the [.Net Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851) on your other laptop.

If you have an installation project, you can have this happen automatically when the application is installed on another computer.